# date_diff on 12:59 to 1:00 gives almost 12 hour difference

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `date_diff` on a start time and an end time. When the start time is 12:59:58 and the end time is 01:00:00, the difference I get is 11:59:58 (instead of 2 seconds). While it seems clear what is happening here, how exactly can I fix it? This seems like a bug to me, but might be an issue on my part.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function getGPSData($siteID, $fromDate, $toDate)
{
    global $pdo;

    $GPSarray = array();
    $maxGPS;
    $minGPS;
    $avgGPS;
    $totalGPS=new DateTime("@0",new DateTimeZone("UTC"));//new DateTime("@0");
    $totalEvents=0;

    $query = "SELECT id, siteID, call_type, start_time, end_time FROM call_log WHERE siteID=:siteID AND (start_time BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate) AND (end_time BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate) AND call_type IN ('LrrpOneTimeReq','LrrpStoreReq','LrrpUseStoredReq')";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":siteID", $siteID);
    $stmt->bindParam(":fromDate", $fromDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(":toDate", $toDate);
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
          //HERE IS THE DATE_DIFF
        $timeDiff = date_diff(new DateTime($row['start_time'],new DateTimeZone("UTC")),new DateTime($row['end_time'],new DateTimeZone("UTC")), true); //force absolute
        //echo $row['id'] . " --- difference between " . $row['start_time'] . " AND " . $row['end_time'] . " is " . $timeDiff->format("%H:%i:%s") . "<br />";
        if(!isset($maxGPS) OR dateIntervalInSeconds($timeDiff) > dateIntervalInSeconds($maxGPS))
        {   $maxGPS = $timeDiff; echo "from " . $row['id'] . " where start=" . $row['start_time'] . " AND end=" . $row['end_time'] . ", maxGPS is now " . $maxGPS->format("%H:%I:%S") . "<br /><br />"; }
        if(!isset($minGPS) OR dateIntervalInSeconds($timeDiff) < dateIntervalInSeconds($minGPS))
            $minGPS = $timeDiff;
        $totalGPS->add($timeDiff);
        $totalEvents++;
    }

    if($totalEvents!=0)
    {
        //$avgGPS=round($totalGPS->getTimestamp() / $totalEvents);
        $avgGPS = average_time($totalGPS->format("H:i:s"),$totalEvents,0);
    }
    else
    {
        $avgGPS=0;
        $maxGPS=new DateInterval('PT0S');
        $minGPS=new DateInterval('PT0S');
    }
    //$avgSeconds = new DateInterval("PT" . $avgGPS . "S");
    $GPSarray['max'] = $maxGPS->format("%H:%I:%S");
    $GPSarray['min'] = $minGPS->format("%H:%I:%S");
    $GPSarray['avg'] = $avgGPS;//gmdate("H:i:s",$avgGPS);//$avgSeconds->format("%H:%i:%s");
    $GPSarray['total'] =  $totalGPS->format("H:i:s");
    $GPSarray['events'] = $totalEvents;

    return $GPSarray;

}
```

Comment: *My* clock changes to 13:00 after 12:59...

Comment: Yes I thought it was an error in the code but it's an error in the data not being inserted properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the data being inserted disregarded AM/PM, so all data would use 12 hour format but the code was treating it as 24 hour format.